# Textarea resize

Tags: html, css, textarea

I need to use a textarea to show some text. The problem is that if I place 4-5 rows of text a scrollbar will appear. How can I use CSS/HTML so that the textarea will be as large as it's content (no scrollbar).

- the textarea doesn't need to change it's size dynamicaly, I use it only to show a text (I could also use a disabled textarea)
- I want the textarea to stretch only verticaly.

If you want to know:
I use the textarea to show some text from a database, so when the textarea (with the text in it) is created, it should show the whole text at once with no scrollbars.

Comment: The whole point of a textarea is for let the user enter text. If you want to show text, use an element with appropriate semantics (maybe div, p or pre).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I´m afraid you´ll have to resort to javascript to set the height of your textarea. You can use the `scrollHeight` property to determine the total height.

Alternatively you could just use a `div` and style the `div` to look like a textarea. The `div` will grow automatically and as it´s a disabled textarea anyway, you don´t really need it to be a textarea.

Answer (score 12):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>autoresizing textarea</title>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
    border: 0 none white;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    resize: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init (maxH) {
        var text = document.getElementById('text');
    var maxHeight=maxH;
    var oldHeight=  text.scrollHeight;
    var newHeight;
    function resize () {

    text.style.height = 'auto';
    newHeight= text.scrollHeight;
    if(newHeight>oldHeight && newHeight>maxHeight  )
    {
        text.style.height=oldHeight+'px';

    }
    else{
        text.style.height = newHeight+'px';
        oldHeight=  text.scrollHeight;
    }

    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize () {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init(200);">
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TDAcr/

Comment: Brilliant, Amin! I feel like I've struck gold on the internet by finding this. You deserve way more than four votes, but I only have the one vote I can give you.

Answer (score 6):

Alright, I just found this and it works very nicely:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function textAreaAdjust(o) {
    o.style.height = "1px";
    o.style.height = (25+o.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I shouldn't assume that you know Javascript (but you might).

Just run

```
textAreaAdjust(document.getElementById("id of your text area"))
```

Something like that should work.  I'm not the best with Javascript (not even close, I just started using it the other day)

That seems to do something similar to what you want.  The first code example is for a textarea that dynamically changes based on what is in it (while typing).  It will take a couple of changes to get it how you want.

Comment: I know javascript but I don't want to use it here. Also, I said the textarea doesn't have to be editable, or change it's size while writing in it. It just needs to show the entire text in it(when the page loads) without a scrollbar.

Comment: I know C++, I could also create that macro but... Where's the fun? xD

Comment: Lots and lots.  It's better to create a clean written site instead of working with a hacked up thing.  Especially when dealing with clients.

Comment: It's my personal site. I always think: "ok, the bad is done; I'll make the next website twice as better!"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS height: and width: attributes, e. g. something like
`<textarea style="width:400px;height:300px">...</textarea>`, just use the sizes you want to.

In addition, if you want to suppress the scrollbar, use `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: The problem is that the text shown has variable size, so I can't say "width:300px;" . One textarea can be 200px tal and another can be 800px ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use div like textarea. It is possible like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width:250px; border:1px solid #777" ></div
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the height of the font you will most likely be displaying it in.  I'm not sure about CSS/HTML but you could use Javascript/PHP/ASP.net to use map to determine how big the text will be based on the number of characters.  If you do it in a monospaced font, this will be even easier.  Why use a text area when you could just use a label which will do the same thing all by itself?

Comment: I use a textarea because it's a website I've made some time ago, and then I did it using textarea, I can't change that.  I mean, when you type in a div, span, the div auto-resizes. Can't I "activate" that autoresize in textarea too?:D

Comment: Well, each control is made to do different things.  Textareas are purposely made so that they don't resize.  What is the reason that your are required to use the textarea?

Comment: Because I've created a website a year ago, that let's you add some Advertisments (containing text). Back then I dit it using textareas, and now I want to change a bit the way they look. I don't want to go through all the adverts already posted and replace the "textarea" with a div.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I've never really made a html/css only site before.  All of my stuff is asp.net and it's all single page changes.  Oh well :)  Try y other solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using JavaScript you can use approach from one of following articles:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/
http://scvinodkumar.wordpress.com/2009/05/28/auto-grow-textarea-doing-it-the-easy-way-in-javascript/

But from your questing I assume you want pure CSS solution.
Then you can just mimic appereance of textarea using simple div and following css (if you just want to display text):

```
div {
    cursor: text;
    background: lightGray;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-family: monospace;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}
```

Comment: The "bad" is already done. I've used textarea in the pages I've created before and I want to do this to all of them without changing anything to the page, only changing the CSS filme

Comment: It's impossible with CSS (even with CSS3). You have to resort to using of little piece of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `name` attribute is not used. You can use this alternative (HTML5):

http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/T3eke/

Comment: Wtf? Every time I press enter in the div, something odd happenes :)) It creates another div inside that one.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [resize property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp) works these days:

> resize: none;